# Joomla 3.1.5 own module with database, sql ignore

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I try create simple module for Joomla 3.1.5

Module in no problem install but code in sql install file is ignored. When I uninstall module uninstall script work.

My code in instalaction sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__mylist_songs`(
`song_id` int(11) not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
`name` varchar(255) not null,
`author` varchar(150) not null
)Engine=MyIsam  default charset=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__mylist_vote`(
`vote_id` int(11) not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
`song_id` int(11) not null,
`ip` varchar(26),
`vote_date` datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)Engine=MyIsam  default charset=utf8;
```

in module xml

```
 <install>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install> <files>

        <filename module="mod_mylist">mod_mylist.php</filename>
        <filename>script.php</filename>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>mod_mylist.xml</filename>
        <filename>sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
        <filename>sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <folder>sql/mysql</folder>
        <folder>sql/mysql/updates</folder>
    </files>
    <scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

But after install module in DB is not change. When I have syntax error in uninstall sql script joomla show error but when the in install installation is done without errors.

I don't understand why. Path's are correct I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <install>
            <sql>
                <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">sql/mysql/install.sql</file>
            </sql>
        </install>
    <uninstall>
            <sql>
                <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">sql/mysql/uninstall.sql</file>
            </sql>
        </uninstall>
```

And the install.sql file should have the query. Also make sure the DB user have permission to add new tables. For [more](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database)

Hope its helps..

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately it did not help. User have permission. Script is correct. File name is change in filesystem and xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following for your XML:

```
<files>
    <filename module="mod_mylist">mod_mylist.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
    <folder>sql</folder>
</files>
```

I've removed references to the actual SQL files as they don't need to be defined if you're calling them in the `<install>` tag and clean up the rest of it.

Comment: Problem is "solved". Install script work when module is install from zip file. Where is install from "discover" option, or install from tmp directory.

Comment: @110precent - ahh fair enough. you should have mentioned that in your question ;)